# C++ How do I concatenate literals with integers?

Tags: c++

I am trying to concatenate a literal with an integer.

The problem is when using the + operator to concatenate a literal with an integer, it tells me "`error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [17]' to binary 'operator+`'".

This is the relevant code :

```
if ( ( A == 0 ) | ( B == 0 ) ) {

    cout << "Sorry, gcd(" + A + ',' + B + ") is undefined.\n";
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Change each `+` to `<<`.

Comment: If you're just trying to output it to a stream, use `<<`

Comment: [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) exists..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for concatenation here, let `cout` do all the heavy lifting for you--its `<<` operator can handle `int`'s after all!

```
cout << "Sorry, gcd(" << A << ',' << B << ") is undefined.\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way using the code snippet you provided:

```
if( ( A == 0 ) || ( B == 0 ) ){
    cout << "Sorry, gcd(" << A << ',' << B << ") is undefined.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that Your `or` statement was incorrect. You were missing a second “`|`”

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::stringstream`:

```cpp
std::stringstream result;
result << "A string plus a number: " << 33;
```

And get a `string` if you want to use it elsewhere:

```cpp
std::string s = result.str();
```